# Upgrade from apache 2.4.7 to 2.4.18 for http/2

Tags: apache

I was able to upgrade our server from apache 2.4.7 to 2.4.18. After the upgrade I discovered that http2 is not enable by default so I decided to run the command:

```
a2enmod http2
```

and restart our server but looking at the http2 indicator on chrome still it doesn't run on http2 is there anything else that I might be forgetting to have http2 working on our website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you must enable it in the configuration using the `Protocols` command.

See [mod_http2](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_http2.html).